# Using 'secure' and 'login' handlers with WSGI/threadsafe in Appegine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi

It's extremely unclear to me from the Appengine documentation how to use both the `app.yaml` configuration settings and the `webapp2` framework.

For example, the documentation suggestions this:

```
- url: /youraccount/.*
  script: accounts.py
  login: required
  secure: always
```

However, that `accounts.py` is the CGI form; not compatible with the `main.app` way of doing things.

Here's some permutations that I've tried and have **failed** for various reasons:

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

- url: /admin/.*
  secure: always
  login: required
```

Above fails because a script is required

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

- url: /admin/.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
  login: required
```

Above fails because the `secure` and `login` directives seem to be ignored.

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.py
  secure: always
  login: required
```

Above fails because the CGI style of handler is not compatible with `threadsafe`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

- url: /admin/.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
  login: required
```

The handlers in the `app.yaml` file are [searched top-down](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Required_Elements), and the first possible match is used. So, the symptom that "the `secure` and `login` directives seem to be ignored" is because the URL is matching the first directive (`- url: /.*`), and not applying your other options.

Basically, switch the order, with the most specific patterns first.

```
- url: /admin/.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
  login: required

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```